# What does it mean for a polymer to absorb water and how does this relate to hydrophobicity?

Tags: materials, plastic, material-science

My materials teacher mentioned a polymer that is used for its hydrophobic properties but also can absorb water. How can a polymer do both of these things?

Comment: Perhaps your teacher is using hydrophobic to refer to low surface energy which makes the material difficult to wet? This might be different from water molecules being absorbed into the molecular structure of the material.

Comment: Good question! FWIW there's always at least some small but still easily measurable water absorption for freshly molded (ie quite dry) parts, even for hydrophobic plastics like PP. Also, hydrophobicity is to do with surface tension / surface energy, producing the angle at the 3-phase contact line. Water absorption can be either a 2-phase rate or equilibrium (if immersed), or 3-phase (in humid air).

Comment: I think I understand... So hydrophobicity means water doesn't want to stick to the surface, but something that's hydrophobic can still absorb water given long enough exposure?

Comment: @nwsteg I have used it heard both ways so in real world usage it means what the person wants it to mean.

Comment: For hydrophilic/hydrophobic, there is a specific quantitative measure against which the terms are defined. "Contact angle". There are slight variations of the measurement setup. The angle which you declare to be "phobic" or "philic" is a little arbitrary. For water absorption, there are also specific tests that are done, and here there might be more significant variation, compared to with contact angle. Importantly, there is the issue of rate vs equilibrium amount. As with a lot of things we call "material properties", numbers coming from different tests, are useful for different contexts.

Comment: re: contact angle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle